# node removeListener does not work

Tags: node.js, listener

trying to remove listener with this code:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var emitter = new EventEmitter;

emitter.on('message', function(text)
{
        console.log(text);
});

setInterval(function()
{
        emitter.emit('message', Date.now());
}, 300);

setTimeout(function()
{
        emitter.removeListener('message', function()
        {
                console.log('removing "message" listener');
        });
}, 1000);
```

It doesn't break the interval, my node version: v0.8.11

reading documentation i think it's ok:
http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to pass the same function to `removeListener`, so in this case you can not use an anonymous function.

Here's a working version:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var emitter = new EventEmitter;

function listener(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

emitter.on('message', listener);

setInterval(function() {
  emitter.emit('message', Date.now());
}, 300);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("removing");
  emitter.removeListener('message', listener);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: How can I pass the same function in both 'on' and 'removeListener'? I want to perform different things on both the listeners. How to achieve this?