# Stop listening to complete event from request library

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I have the following nodejs code

```
'use strict';
const request = require('request');
var stream;

function connect() {
    stream = request({
        url: 'https://cloud-sse.xxx.com/stable/stocksUS?token=YOUR_TOKEN&symbols=spy',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'
        }
    })
}

stream.on('complete', () => {
    console.log("Reconnecting");
    connect();
});
```

At some point, I would like to stop listening to **complete** event.

May I know, what is the proper way to achieve so?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't use JQuery. I use Nodejs only.

Comment: My fault, sorry for that, I got confused when I saw `.on()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `.once()` rather than `.on()`?

Comment: I have no idea regarding `.once`. I merely follow the example from API document.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `.once()` will listen only one time to the `event`, in that case that will be the way to go. However, he may want to listen multiple times, but stop listening when some condition triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [removeListener()](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_removelistener), but you have to avoid the usage of anonymous functions ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075793/node-removelistener-does-not-work)).

**Example:**

```
'use strict';
const request = require('request');
var stream;

function connectHandler()
{
    console.log("Reconnecting");

    stream = request({
        url: 'https://cloud-sse.xxx.com/stable/stocksUS?token=YOUR_TOKEN&symbols=spy',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'
        }
    });
}

stream.on('complete', connectHandler);
```

And later you can do this, when you want to remove the listener:

```
stream.removeListener('complete', connectHandler);
```

If you don't mind to remove all the listener on the `complete` event, you can always do

```
stream.removeAllListeners('complete');
```

Comment: What if I can't avoid using anonymous function? As, my anonymous function is more complex than the given example.

Comment: How you can't avoid using anonymous function? You can always declare a function that does the same job. Example: `() => {console.log("Reconnecting"); connect();}` can be replaced by `function connectHandler() {console.log("Reconnecting"); connect();}` and use `connectHandler` on `.on()` and `.removeListener()`.

Comment: As my anonymous function rely on its parent function parameters.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng well, you can use [removeAllListeners()](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname), but that will remove all handlers for `complete` event.

Comment: I think I will stick to `removeAllListeners`. Thanks.