# discord.js client.off fails

Tags: node.js, events, discord.js, listener

I want to reload the code used for events in discord.js. The code is currently stored in a collection (the same way as commands in the discord.js guide). I have the following code:

```js
client.events.delete(args[0]);
const file = require(`../events/${args[0]}.js`);
client.off(file.name, (...eventArgs) => this.events.get(file.name).run(this.client, this.shared, ...eventArgs));
message.reply(`Removed ${file.name} event.`);
```

The events are added to the listener using this:

```js
for (const file of readdirSync('./events').filter(check => check.endsWith('.js'))) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    this.shared.logger.log('info', `Loaded event ${event.name}`);
    this.shared.events.set(event.name, event);
}

this.events.forEach(event => {
    const file = require(`./events/${event.name}.js`);
    this.client.on(file.name, (...eventArgs) => this.events.get(file.name).run(this.client, this.shared, ...eventArgs));
});
```

This runs without error, then when the event that was removed is triggered I get the following error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (E:\Files\code\bot\index.js:85:73)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketManager.debug (E:\Files\code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:125:17)
    at WebSocketShard.debug (E:\Files\code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:168:18)
    at WebSocketShard.sendHeartbeat (E:\Files\code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:557:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Files\code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:529:73)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

I assume this is caused because `client.off` isn't removing the event from the listener, but is deleting it from the collection, meaning that it is undefined when that event is triggered and the error is caused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node removeListener does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075793/node-removelistener-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Discord event is always on. If you try to remove it, it will still persist until you've terminated the program, so you'd get the error. Try using `this.client.once` instead, and recall it when the desired event is needed.